# Issue with RELP/TLS and 100% cpu

Tags: ssl, rsyslog

I am running into an issue trying to use RELP/TLS. Rsyslog 7.6.2 is
installed on all machines. To make matters worse the problem goes away when running under `rsyslog -nd` on both client and server.

The issue presents shortly after the RELP client connects to the RELP
server. I get a handful of log lines and then it all falls apart. I have
managed to strace the thread that is handling the connections and observed
that after a short period of time rsyslog enters a tight loop on a writev
to the RELP client. I haven't tried to inspect much on the RELP client side
beyond debug mode.

Any suggestions?

```
setsockopt(29, SOL_TCP, TCP_CORK, [1], 4) = 0
writev(29,
[{"\27\3\3\1\0\377\357\303\346\317\361L&{K\347S\324M\257L\354/\254U\305\26\2251\332{U"...,
261}], 1) = 261
setsockopt(29, SOL_TCP, TCP_CORK, [0], 4) = 0
recvfrom(29, "\27\3\3\0\340", 5, 0, NULL, NULL) = 5
recvfrom(29,
"\216fn\267y\10,\233\270\277\272#c\327\267\3548E\255\300\244;b\355A.\1\207+^\2236"...,
224, 0, NULL, NULL) = 224
setsockopt(29, SOL_TCP, TCP_CORK, [1], 4) = 0
writev(29,
[{"\27\3\3\0\320\314\231U\0160\342\320G\347X\37\265\353\36\2134vcV->]\215\364\306
L"..., 213}], 1) = 2
writev(29,
[{"\3\0\320\314\231U\0160\342\320G\347X\37\265\353\36\2134vcV->]\215\364\306
La\352"..., 211}], 1) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
... and on and on and on
```